# Intel xdk, "Shutdown (name of app)" to pop up on back button

Tags: intel-xdk

I would like to have the pop up "Shutdown (name of app)" on the back button and not on the default button that is right now..(Intel xdk app framework)
How could i do that? Please help me!

Comment: do u want shutdown instead of back button ? can u explain more?

Comment: when i press the hardware backbutton i need the app to pop up the window "shutdown (name of app)", it already has a hardware button that shutsdown the app by default (its the button that looks like a cube) and i would like instead of pressing that cube button to press the backbutton

Answer (score 0):

For that Add a custom header like.........

```
<div class="panel" title="Custom title" data-footer="footer_1" data-header='custom-header' id="page_5" data-appbuilder-object="page">
   <div class="container" id="page_5_container" style="width:100%" data-appbuilder-object="container" data-position="static">
      your content here...............
   </div>
</div>

<header id="custom-header" data-appbuilder-object="header">
   <a id="backButton"  onclick="popup()" class="button back" style="visibility: visible; ">Back</a>
   <h1 id="pageTitle" class="">
      Custom title
   </h1>
</header>
```